# Is there a way to see the total number of votes per/{day|week|*} on a given site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, voting, statistics

I'm curious about the variance in total voting activity across the network. For instance, it seems that there is a strong correlation between # of answers and votes on SE, but on other sites, a question with several answers may have no votes.

Possibly as a column on this page?
https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)... sort of.

For moderators on a site, a breakdown of voting rates over time is available as part of analytics.

For everyone else, a big sum of voting to date is available via the [/stats API call](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/methods/stats).  You can diff that over time.

It does track so well with activity on a site that I doubt we'll ever expose it as part of our network sites' rolling stats, since it'd be redundant.